# Number to words currency decimal

Tags: c#, numbers, decimal, number-formatting

I have this code to get Numbers to words and it works, but I have a requirement for my application and that is :

Example 1 : What the program does, let's take this number : 27,59 - The code will take me to "doua sute sapte zeci si 59 bani. Is ok, but :

Example 2 : When the number is 27.00 the result is : doua zeci si sapte si 00 bani, and the result I want only when some number has .00 to cut the 'si 00 bani' and get from 27.00 = doua zeci si sapte lei than doua zeci si sapte lei si 00 bani.
Thank you

```
  private static string[] _ones =
        {
            "",
            "unu",
            "doua",
            "trei",
            "patru",
            "cinci",
            "sase",
            "sapte",
            "opt",
            "noua"
        };

        private static string[] _teens =
        {
            "zece",
            "unsprezece",
            "doisprezece",
            "treisprezece",
            "paisprezece",
            "cincisprezece",
            "saisprezece",
            "saptisprezece",
            "optsprezece",
            "nouasprezece"
        };

        private static string[] _tens =
        {
            "",
            "zece",
            "douazeci",
            "treizeci",
            "patruzeci",
            "cincizeci",
            "saizeci",
            "saptezeci",
            "optzeci",
            "nouazeci"
        };

        // US Nnumbering:
        private static string[] _thousands =
        {
            "",
            "mie",
            "milion",
            "miliard",
            "trilion",
            "catralion"
        };
string digits, temp;
            bool showThousands = false;
            bool allZeros = true;

            // Use StringBuilder to build result
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            // Convert integer portion of value to string
            digits = ((long)value).ToString();
            // Traverse characters in reverse order
            for (int i = digits.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int ndigit = (int)(digits[i] - '0');
                int column = (digits.Length - (i + 1));

                // Determine if ones, tens, or hundreds column
                switch (column % 3)
                {
                    case 0:        // Ones position
                        showThousands = true;
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            // First digit in number (last in loop)
                            temp = String.Format("{0} ", _ones[ndigit]);
                        }
                        else if (digits[i - 1] == '1')
                        {
                            // This digit is part of "teen" value
                            temp = String.Format("{0} ", _teens[ndigit]);
                            // Skip tens position
                            i--;
                        }
                        else if (ndigit != 0)
                        {
                            // Any non-zero digit
                            temp = String.Format("{0} ", _ones[ndigit]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // This digit is zero. If digit in tens and hundreds
                            // column are also zero, don't show "thousands"
                            temp = String.Empty;
                            // Test for non-zero digit in this grouping
                            if (digits[i - 1] != '0' || (i > 1 && digits[i - 2] != '0'))
                                showThousands = true;
                            else
                                showThousands = false;
                        }

                        // Show "thousands" if non-zero in grouping
                        if (showThousands)
                        {
                            if (column > 0)
                            {
                                temp = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                                    temp,
                                    _thousands[column / 3],
                                    allZeros ? " " : ", ");
                            }
                            // Indicate non-zero digit encountered
                            allZeros = false;
                        }
                        builder.Insert(0, temp);
                        break;

                    case 1:        // Tens column
                        if (ndigit > 0)
                        {
                            temp = String.Format("{0}{1}",
                                _tens[ndigit],
                                (digits[i + 1] != '0') ? " si " : " ");
                            builder.Insert(0, temp);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:        // Hundreds column
                        if (ndigit > 0)
                        {
                            temp = String.Format("{0} sute ", _ones[ndigit]);
                            builder.Insert(0, temp);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            builder.AppendFormat("lei si {0:00} bani", (value - (long)value) * 100);


            // Capitalize first letter
            return String.Format("{0}{1}",
                Char.ToUpper(builder[0]),
                builder.ToString(1, builder.Length - 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a condition to check the decimal value. An easy way to do this is the `Decimal.Remainder()` method provided by .net.

Just change this

```
builder.AppendFormat("lei si {0:00} bani", (value - (long)value) * 100);
```

To include a condition for your 00...

```
// You always need "lei" right?
builder.AppendFormat("lei");

// This code simply divides the decimal value by 1; and only adds "si NN bani" if there's a remainder
if (Decimal.Remainder(value, 1) > 0) {
    builder.AppendFormat(" si {0:00} bani", (value - (long)value) * 100);
}
```

Comment: I always need lei but I need instead of 27.00 to say 'doua zeci si sapte lei' without 00 bani if the decimal is 27.00 only if it is zero, your code will remove 00 bani only if the value is 0 I need to remove 'si 00 bani' only if value is 27.00 if the decimal point value is 00 after the actual number

Comment: @user3144640: Ok, my hasty mistake. Fixed!

Comment: Thank you a million, I would be extremely thankful if you could help me in another matter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390366/currency-to-words-mispelling-problems this is the link help me please